# Cant read dir of /etc/my.cnf. (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am running MariaDB (libmysql - 5.5.41-MariaDB) and today I noticed that I couldn't go to mysql via command line to create a dump file. It would throw an error:

> mysql: Can't read dir of '/etc/my.cnf.' (Errcode: 2)
>   Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted

Not sure why it needs to read a directory named "my.cnf." but I do see a directory called "my.cnf.d" in etc folder. Possibly a typo of some sort but when I went to my my.cnf file, I didn't notice any settings for this. The only thing closely relates to it is this:

```
#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

This is something that recently occurred without me changing anything in the settings so I am not sure what is going on with mariadb. Any help would be appreciated.

> EDIT: Okay, I solved the issue by doing mkdir my.cnf. (not sure what
>   this directory is needed for as nothing is inside it. Never changed
>   anything to my.cnf for it to start requiring this directory..

Comment: A typo somewhere in the real `my.cnf`?

Comment: Make sure any directories being called by `!includedir` exist and that you have permission to access them.  Also, it would help to see the full `my.cnf` file, to see if there are any errors in it.  Plus, make sure your user's `~/.my.cnf` is accurate as well.

Comment: What happens when you run `mysql --no-defaults ...` ?

Comment: @iain that seems to work, I get "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

Comment: @Gene the my.cnf.d directory does exist, here is the permissions. `drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root     4096 Mar  3 15:53 my.cnf.d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it works when you disable reading the defaults (--no-defaults) then the problem is located somewhere in the default files, their permissions or the permissions of the directories containing them.

Carefully examine the permissions on /etc, /etc/my.cnf, /etc/my.cnf.d, the files inside /etc/my.cnf.d as well as for good measure ~/.my.cnf.

Check the contents of each file for more includes and any other directives that may access files.

If SELinux is enabled, check the contents of /var/log/audit.log for relevant AVC denied entries.

Comment: I'm not sure what permission it should be set to nor do I know which are the default files. The error is throwing that it can't read directory 'my.cnf.' and I can see that I do not have a directory named 'my.cnf.', I do have directory 'my.cnf.d' so not sure what to do from there or where can I go to correct this.

Comment: Okay, I solved the issue by doing `mkdir my.cnf.` (not sure what this directory is needed for as nothing is inside it. Never changed anything to my.cnf for it to start requiring this directory..

Answer (score 8):

the solution actually is simple.

```
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

is your last line on /etc/my.cnf, so mysql can't read complete '/etc/my.cnf.d' only '/etc/my.cnf.'

You just need add one more line so mysql can read its.

```
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
# add new line here
```

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Comment: @triads  can you please explain what is new line to add end my.cnf file

Answer (score 1):

You must add new empty line after !includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

EMPTY LINE

You must simply press 'enter' in the end of this line:!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

Comment: This worked for me; after I had edited the said file I removed this empty line inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange: The failure occured also suddenly (after restarting the docker container) - in `MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, Debian 9.5, Docker 17.12.1-ce`

Trying a lot of stuff didn't work, all permissions where correct (afaik).

The last option was to follow the "Edit" of the question-author and that worked!

I did:

```
mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/_my.cnf    # there was just the line [mysql] in it, nothing else
mkdir /etc/my.cnf
chown mysql:mysql /etc/my.cnf
```

now after running `service mysql start` it suddenly says: "A MySQL Server is already started".
After `service mysql restart` all is working like before the shutdown of the docker conatainer.

Answer (score 0):

This no Connection happens to me every couple times I restart my MacBook. I think it has something to do with competing versions of Mysql. Native Mac MySql VS. Brew MySql. 
This is all I need to do:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```

Then restart my terminal. 
I reference this article every month or two 
The `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` has an includes for `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d` directory, and that fails if the directory isn't there. 
So I just need to create the directory. Annoying little bug, but easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in macOS Catalina mariadb.

```
mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d

brew services stop mariadb

brew services start mariadb
```

[image]